# JavaScript change first instance of paragraph style with another

Tags: javascript, styles, adobe-indesign, paragraph

I need help writing a JavaScript that will search for the first instance of a paragraph style in each text box and then replace it with another paragraph style. If there's a way to do that with a grep, that'd be good too. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you found/tried so far?

Comment: Hey, please show us what you have tried. We will not create a script for you. All we can do is help you improve what you have or push you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Some work points you should face developing this

- 1st all the script inherits the Application class.
- get the page you are working on - class Page
- Get all the pageItems - ItemPage or PageItem (I don't remember now)
- Loop through pageItems and get all the textframes within the document - TextFrame Class
- Using a loop get from all the textframes the first paragraph. something like

  pageItem[i].textFrame[i].paragraph[0]

  - Put the paragraph in a variable, use the documentation on the script and change the desired styles

A good reading reference for you

[Jongware page](http://www.jongware.com/idjshelp.html)